Magnetic field due to real solenoid
In this question from the book 'Problems in general physics by IE Irodov. I think the tangential component of the magnetic field for r>R given is incorrect. The solutions on the internet come to this expression by considering that the entirety of the current in the solenoid passes through an amperian circular loop around the wire. But this expression does not converge to 0 for ideal solenoid in which the loops are infinitely close together. I arrived at the answer by considering only the normal component of the current density vector at point at which it crosses the loop. Is my logic correct.
